# Не могу нажать на ссылку

Tags: html, css

Не могу нажать на ссылку в header. Даже если при абсолютном позиционировании ставлю z-index 9999 все равно, тупо не могу кликнуть, как будто кликаю на картинку. Даже не знаю в чем может быть проблема.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

 var st = $(this).scrollTop();

 $('.header-img').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0%, ' + st / 100 + '%'
 });

 $('.get-start').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0%, -' + st   + '%'
 });
});
```

```css
.get-start{
 width: 19%;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 40%;
 background-color: var(--ThemeColor);
 text-decoration: none;
 color: var(--BgColor);
 font-size: 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 70%;
}
.header-img-container{
 top:-100px;
 z-index: -1;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-img-container">
  <img class="header-img" src="<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>">
  <a class="get-start" href="#">GET START WITH US</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: ваш пример (если его запустить) ничего не отображает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не закрыт `img`, добавьте `/` в конец и ограничьте размер изображения(получается, что картинка не закрывает ссылку, а растягивает контейнер для нее за экраном, и ее не видно) и задавайте размеры родительскому блоку куда вкладываете абсолют, а то на малых экранах так ничего не увидите, лучше абсолют в крайних случаях поэтому использовать:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.header-img').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0%, ' + st / 100 + '%'
  });

  $('.get-start').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0%, -' + st + '%'
  });
});
```

```css
.get-start {
  width: 19%;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40%;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
}

.header-img-container {
  top: -100px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
}

.header-img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-img-container">
  <img class="header-img" src="https://zelenyjmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Sibirskaya-koshka-51.jpg" />
  <a class="get-start" href="#">GET START WITH US</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Тег img один из немногих, которому не требуется закрывающий (как и <br>, например).

Comment: да, но там закрывающего слеша вконце нет `<img src="URL" alt="альтернативный текст" />`, но вы правы, в html5 он не обязательный

Comment: Раньше он нужен был?! Бедные люди, как жили вообще... Хорошо что мне не пришлось переживать эти ужасы)

Comment: Можете пережить еще, поверстайте почтовую рассылку